# Why is $\bigcup\limits_{|c| \leq 1} cU$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I have a question about proposition in this set of notes (https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/TVS.pdf) on topological vector spaces.

[image]

We are in a complex vector space $V$.  A subset $S$ is said to be **convex** if for any $v, w \in S$, $tv +(1-t)w \in S$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, **balanced** if $|c| = 1, v \in S$ implies $cv \in S$.

In the proof, it says we replace a convex neighborhood $U$ of $0$ with the union $$\bigcup\limits_{|c| \leq 1} cU$$  It is clear that this union is balanced, but I don't understand why it should remain convex.

Comment: Since $U$ is convex and contains 0, you can show that $U = \bigcup_{|c| \le 1} cU$.

Comment: I don't think that's true.  Otherwise, why would anyone bother with the definition of balanced?

Comment: I don't see why the equality would render useless the definition of balanced. Note that the assumptions that $U$ is convex and contains 0 are important here. Which of the containments $U \subseteq \bigcup_{|c|\le 1} cU$ and $\bigcup_{|c|\le 1} cU \subseteq U$ do you disagree with?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: But convexity only tells you that $|c|u + (1-|c|)0 = |c|u \in U$, not $cu$.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: For a counterexample with real scalars, take $U$ to be the interior of a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing the origin. The union $\bigcup_{|c| \leq 1} cU$ looks like a bowtie and certainly isn't convex.